# Concatenating 'N' 2D arrays in NumPy with varying dimensions into one 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, keras, numpy-ndarray

I have N samples of 2D features with variable dimensions along one axis. For example:

- Sample 1 : (100,20)
- Sample 2 : (150,20)
- Sample 3 : (90,20)

  Is there a way to combine all N samples into a 3D array so that the first dimension (N,?,?) denotes the sample number?

PS: I wish to avoid padding and reshaping, and want to find a way to input the features with their dimensions intact into an LSTM network in Keras. Any other suggestions to achieve the same are welcome.

Comment: A 3d array with those arrays is impossible.  Are you sure `keras` can work with mixed sizes?

Comment: Keras LSTM does allow : `model.add(LSTM(units, input_shape=(None, 20)))` .So I guess mixed sizes shouldn't be an issue. Need further clarifications on this though.

Comment: The `None` dimension is samples, which is unknown during setup. It will be different during training and testing.  You may need to do more reading on `keras` models.

Comment: The Keras documentation indicates that the None is the timesteps and not samples: `3D tensor with shape (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim)`. We pass on a 3D array as input to the LSTM which then interprets it as `(samples, None, 20)`. So that was my very question: if Keras does allow using None, can either one of timesteps or sequence-length not vary in size?
Source: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

Answer (score 1):

Keras does allow for variable length input to an LSTM but within a single batch all inputs must have the same length. A way to reduce the padding needed would be to batch your input sequences together based on their length and only pad up to the maximum length within each batch. For example you could have one batch with sequence length 100 and another with sequence length 150. But I'm afraid there is no way to completely avoid padding. During inference you can use any sequence length.